# ImportError: Dependencies for InstructorEmbedding not found, while it is installed

Tags: python, langchain, sentence-transformers

I already installed `InstructorEmbedding`, but it keeps giving me the error, in jupyter notebook environment using Python 3.12 (I also tried in 3.11). Kernel restarting didn't help.

```py
import torch
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings

DEVICE = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"


embedding = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", model_kwargs={"device": DEVICE})
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/huggingface.py:151, in HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    150 try:
--> 151     from InstructorEmbedding import INSTRUCTOR
    153     self.client = INSTRUCTOR(
    154         self.model_name, cache_folder=self.cache_folder, **self.model_kwargs
    155     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/InstructorEmbedding/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .instructor import *

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/InstructorEmbedding/instructor.py:9
      8 from torch import Tensor, device
----> 9 from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
     10 from sentence_transformers.models import Transformer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 10
      4 DEVICE = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
      6 #loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("aircraft_pdfs")
      7 #docs = loader.load()
      8 #print(len(docs))  # length of all pages together
---> 10 embedding = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", model_kwargs={"device": DEVICE})

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/huggingface.py:157, in HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    153     self.client = INSTRUCTOR(
    154         self.model_name, cache_folder=self.cache_folder, **self.model_kwargs
    155     )
    156 except ImportError as e:
--> 157     raise ImportError("Dependencies for InstructorEmbedding not found.") from e

ImportError: Dependencies for InstructorEmbedding not found.
```

here is the output of `pip freeze`

```
transformers==4.37.2
torch==2.2.0
langchain==0.1.6
InstructorEmbedding==1.0.1
...
```

Comment: "I already installed InstructorEmbedding".  Since that isn't working we'd want to know how you did install it? Did you try running `%conda install conda-forge::instructorembedding` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/instructorembedding) and use of magic install commands) from inside the notebook where you want to use it? You chose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager and so you should always be using that to install things, except if there is no conda recipe. Also we don't see how or where you ran `pip freeze`. That could be from anywhere on your system. ...

Comment: <continued> Do you get the same thing if you run `%pip list` from inside the notebook where you hope to use it? Again, here the use of the magic symbol `%` is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would also need to install [sentence-transformers](/questions/tagged/sentence-transformers). Try installing it via:

```
pip install -U sentence-transformers==2.2.2
```

and then run your code. Please make sure you install the version `2.2.2` otherwise you'll end up with this error:

```
TypeError: INSTRUCTOR._load_sbert_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

It seems the latest version of `sentence-transformers` has some [compatibility issues](https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT/issues/722).

Comment: The OP chose Anaconda/conda and ideally they should stick with that as their package manager for robust and portable environments. An option would be to run `%conda install conda-forge::sentence-transformers` in the notebook where they want to use it and then restart the kernel,  based on [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/sentence-transformers-feedstock).

Comment: Yes, *ideally*. But even in that case you need to specify the version of the package with: `%conda install conda-forge::sentence-transformers==2.2.2`, otherwise it will install the latest version (2.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Import INSTRUCTOR

from InstructorEmbedding import INSTRUCTOR

and install the correct version of sentence_transformer (you probably have version 2.3.1)

!pip uninstall sentence-transformers
!pip install sentence-transformers==2.2.2